# What is the name of this enemy?

Tags: donkey-kong-64

In Angry Aztec, there is a temple with five doors, one for each Kong. I'm not sure in which part of the temple it was, but I think it was in Diddy's. Once you grab the golden banana at the end, you hear someone scream "get out" and a cross hair and time limit appear. If you don't get out in time, you get shot, lose a bit of health and the timer starts over again.

I guess "in-universe", there is some sort of Kremling sniper shooting you from an unseen place. Is there a name for this enemy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sniper's name is [Kroc](https://www.mariowiki.com/Kroc). He appears in a DKC3 level as well as a few times in DK64.